# ReceiveNoWait doesn't work with Apache.NMS & ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic

I met problem when use ReceiveNoWait with Apache.NMS & ActiveMQ, really simple scenarios:

```
private static void Send(string text)
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616/");
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.Start();

        var session = connection.CreateSession();
        var queue = session.GetQueue("test");
        var producer = session.CreateProducer(queue);

        producer.Send(producer.CreateTextMessage(text));
    }
}

private static string Receive()
{
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616/");
    using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    {
        connection.Start();

        var session = connection.CreateSession();
        var queue = session.GetQueue("test");
        var consumer = session.CreateConsumer(queue);

        var message = (ITextMessage)consumer.ReceiveNoWait();
        return message == null ? null : message.Text;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Send(i.ToString());
    }

    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Receive() ?? "(null)");
    }
}
```

Explanation: I sent 100 text messages to the queue and I'm going to receive & print the messages one by one with a while loop. But the code above always print `(null)` - I can find the messages in the queue from admin console.

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This method does not work properly also in `Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ` version `1.6.2`. The workaround is to use equivalent method `IMessage Receive(TimeSpan timeout);`:

```
var message = (ITextMessage)consumer.Receive( TimeSpan.Zero );
```

It's good to add some short timeout: `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 100 )` should work.

Answer (score 0):

How long do you wait for the messages to arrive?  What version of the NMS libraries are you using?  Have you tried adding in a small delay in the final while loop so that the main thread doesn't hog the CPU?

Regards
Tim.

http://fusesource.com

Comment: I've add a 0.5 second delay after each <code>Receive</code> call but still get the same result. I'm using the latest 1.4.x version of Apache.NMS and Apache.NMS.ActiveMQ.

Comment: I'd recommend you create an NUnit test that reproduces the problem case and open a new issue at the ActiveMQ.NET Jira.  Or at least take the question to the ActiveMQ Mailing lists.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a consumer and then directly calling `receiveNoWait()`. The problem is that when you create a consumer, the messages are sent to the consumer asynchronously. So, here you are calling `receiveNoWait()` before any message gets received to the consumer (even though they may exist on the server)

The solution is either to have the consumer open all the time, or wait some time after creating the consumer, or use `receive(timeout)`